# SQL Server 2000 Script to list all Meta Data Services DTS packages

Tags: sql, sql-server, dts

I am doing an SSIS package that would go out to all our DB servers to gather information about them, and what is on them. And in this one case there is a SQL 2000 box with a bunch of DTS packages on there.

Now I can easily list the Local Packages using "`exec sp_enum_dtspackages`", but this doesn't list the Meta Data Services Packages.

I cannot find anything obvious online or in the database to help me with this, not really even then attaching a profiler to it.

So I was hoping someone might be able to help me with a script. I am looking for the name, description, owner and the create_date.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use msdb
go

select no.Name, si.Comments as Description, vai.CreateByUser as Owner, vai.VersionCreateTime as CreateDate
    from RTblNamedObj no
        inner join RtblSumInfo si
            on no.IntID = si.IntID
        inner join rtblVersionAdminInfo vai
            on no.IntID = vai.IntID
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is what I have been looking for! Works perfectly, I just have to do a DISTINCT list now. Cheers.

Comment: This definately works, the only downside is that it will not show you the package if it doesn't have a description. So the workaround is to enter a description.

Comment: @ryk: You can change the INNER JOIN on RtblSumInfo to be a LEFT JOIN instead. That will then get you packages with or without descriptions.

Comment: Yes I can, but then I get back almost 3000 rows of totally unrelated stuff, and I cannot see a way to filter them out, but I am very happy with your answer, and it is working for me. Thanks a lot! I am sure others will find this helpful too!